# how to add template css js and bootstrap in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I want to add bootstrap template in my django app. I have downloaded it and kept in my static folder, then added its path in setting.py file as:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

index.html of template is:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Business Casual - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->

<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'css/business-casual.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<div class="brand">Business Casual</div>
<div class="address-bar">3481 Melrose Place | Beverly Hills, CA 90210
```

...

but doesn't working ,please help me

Comment: I would suggest installing and using this package `django-bootstrap3`. It is Django optimized, easy to use and has good documentation. https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: How exactly is it not working, do you get an error message?

Comment: css and bootstrap doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're running this from `python manage.py runserver` you'll need to include the following in your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If you're running it in production make sure you've run `python manage.py collectstatic`

You'll also need the following in `settings.py`, replacing project with your app

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "project/static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: If you have 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in your INSTALLED_APPS you don't need to add to urlpatterns. It will work on the development server with debug on